# Sending user to user app request in canvas app doesn't display notification

Tags: facebook, notifications, facebook-javascript-sdk, apprequests

I already read all what is needed about missing notifications on user-to-user app request, and it appears it could be :

- because the app is not a canvas or the canvas url is not correct
- because the app is in sand-box mode.

I developped my app in sand-box mode and tried some u2u requests between generated test users with JS SDK last weeks. Everything was fine, notifications did show up...
But starting today, there's no more notification in the page header notification list. To find the request, users apparently have to notice that the small count of the "applications" item in the left menu has changed, even for user-to-user requests.

I can't find this change in the 6th february changes, maybe I missed something. I read somewhere in old posts that the notification policy is determined by Facebook algorithms and that I can't be sure the request will appear in notifications.

But it's clearly written that user-to-user requests provoke notifications here :

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/concepts/requests/

Can someone explain me where this change comes from ?

Thanks in advance !

Pierre

Comment: Is your application still in sandbox mode? Can you post a link to it?

Comment: Number one bug in facebook's bug tracker right now: https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/532388000129311?browse=search_511bf995772fc8763161711

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you Igy, I'm relieved that's not a design change but a bug (I copy once more the link to the bug as this is supposed to be an answer to my question :
https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/532388000129311?browse=search_511bf995772fc8763161711
) !